# Imprimir palabras juntas y en mayusculas java

Tags: java, string, formularios, bucles, netbeans-8.2

Quisiera que me ayuden con este codigo, el programa debe imprimir dos palabras juntas y en mayusculas...ejemplo: ese perro -----> ESEPERRO...espero su ayuda...

```
    String ato = uno.getText();
     uno.setText(ato.toUpperCase());
     String atomo = tres.getText();
     tres.setText(atomo.replace(" ", ""));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes hacer algo de la siguiente manera, es algo simple, pero para que tengas una idea con lo que estás buscando

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Primera Palabra: ");
var one = sc.nextLine();
System.out.print("Segunda Palabra: ");
var two = sc.nextLine();
        String three = one + two;
        var message = three.toUpperCase();

        System.out.println(message);


    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tienes tres cajas de texto: *uno* y *dos* son tus cajas de entrada y *tres* es tu caja de salida. Tu código podría quedar así:

```
String cadena= uno.getText()+dos.getText(); //Concatenas tus dos palabras
String msj = cadena.toUpperCase()); //Conviertes tu cadena a mayúsculas
tres.setText(msj); //Asigna el resultado a tu caja de texto
```

Éste código te va funcionar siempre que en tus cajas de texto solo insertes una palabra.